# select_date is showing number in dropdown not month name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am using select_date function to have dropdown in my view for month name only. But it is giving me number instead of month name in the dropdown. Can anybody help on this?
my code:

```
<%= select_date(Date.today, :order => [:month, :year], :discard_day => true, :use_short_month => true) %>
```

Thanks in advance
Sumanta

Comment: With your code, I get the name of the month in the drop down.  Try reloading the page or if that doesn't work, restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any issue with syntax, I tried the same and got the expected result - Month in dropdown. As suggested please restart your server.

Comment: Well issue was with server suported font - it should be "en". then it will come properly.